# Javascript Regex match string with only one occurrence of __ characters

Tags: regex

I am struggling with some regex to match the strings I need. This is what I have so far, but it's matching more than I want:

```
(\w*__c|\w*__r|[a-zA-Z0-9]*)\.\w*__c|\w*__c
```

Here are some examples of what I want to match/not match:

```
FFX_GLAAssetDisposalID__c                                   => TRUE
FAM__Asset_Sub_Group__r.PNL_On_Asset_Disposal_GL_Account__c => TRUE
Product2.SalesRevenueAccount__c                             => TRUE
ffbext__codabecashmatchingreport                            => FALSE
Product2.c2g__CODASalesRevenueAccount__c                    => FALSE
```

Where items are separated by a . the significant thing is the number of __ in the part after the . where there can be no more than one set of __. I've also experimented with negative lookaheads to no avail.

Comment: Maybe `\b(?:\w+\.)?[^\W_]+(?:_[^\W_]+)*__c\b` is enough? See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F3ZXgn/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew wow, i've been trying to get it for hours - thank you. If you write as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bear in mind that `\w` matches letters, digits *and* underscore. To be able to control the number of underscores, one needs to use `[^\W_]` character class, that is, `\w` with underscore subtracted.

You may use

```
\b(?:\w+\.)?[^\W_]+(?:_[^\W_]+)*__c\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F3ZXgn/1)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:\w+\.)?` - an optional sequence of 1+ letters/digits/underscores and then a `.`
- `[^\W_]+` - one or more letters or digits
- `(?:_[^\W_]+)*` - zero or more sequences of `_` and then one or more letters/digits
- `__c` - a `__c` string
- `\b` - a word boundary